# JavaMail sending with smtp.auth = false ERROR: Invalid Addresses

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I can't get working JAVAmail propertly my BeanDefinition looks like this:

```
  <bean id="blMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    <property name="port" value="8889" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  </bean>
```

The localhost:8889 is forwarded and its 100% working server when I try to send email i get such an error (full log):

```
17:01:26,887 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4

17:01:26,889 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers

17:01:26,889 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers

17:01:26,890 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}

17:01:26,891 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}

17:01:26,892 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map

17:01:26,905 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]

17:01:26,912 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false

17:01:26,913 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 8889, isSSL false

17:01:27,303 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 220 *********************************************************************************************

17:01:27,303 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "localhost", port: 8889
17:01:27,303 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 

17:01:27,305 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) EHLO sPEc-Komputer

17:01:27,682 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-PLWAMS12EX2K7.test.com Hello [192.168.6.1]

17:01:27,682 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-SIZE 10485760

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-PIPELINING

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-DSN

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-AUTH LOGIN

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-8BITMIME

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250-BINARYMIME

17:01:27,683 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 XXXXXXXA

17:01:27,684 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"

17:01:27,684 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""

17:01:27,685 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""

17:01:27,685 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""

17:01:27,685 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN"

17:01:27,685 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""

17:01:27,686 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""

17:01:27,686 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XXXXXXXA", arg ""

17:01:27,698 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false

17:01:27,698 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) MAIL FROM:<test@test.com>

17:01:27,794 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 2.1.0 Sender OK

17:01:27,795 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) RCPT TO:<toTest@test.com>

17:01:32,895 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

17:01:32,895 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Invalid Addresses

17:01:32,895 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP:   toTest@test.com

17:01:32,896 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses

17:01:32,896 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) RSET

17:01:37,993 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 250 2.0.0 Resetting
```

Host addresses, email addresses are replaced by my own addresses (safety) and they are 100% working. Whats more if I send mail to the same mail so RCPT is the same as MAIL FROM its work, other mails (outgoing probalby) don't work. Any ideas how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is configured not to relay messages outside its domain.  You can change the server configuration, or perhaps [you just need to authenticate to the server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay).